# Integrate quickbooks with rails and angularjs application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, quickbooks

I am developing internal CRM for a client, in which it is required to synchronize with quickbooks for all financial transactions.

I am stuck here. I do not know where to start? Someone asked me to start with webconnector. The CRM application is on AngularJs and rails. I searched but couldnot find anything specific to integration of quickbooks desktop with Angularjs and rails.

So Please please can any one there help me out? I want to to know the full process and if any sample code available for the same in rails and angularjs would be great help.

Thanks

Comment: For starters - QuickBooks ONLINE, or QuickBooks DESKTOP? What are the integration requirements? What data do you need to exchange?

Comment: Quickbooks Desktop. The client is currently using method.me which has its own integration tool for quickbooks. The client wishes to make new custom CRM in ROR and Angularjs and wants to integrate it with already license obtained Quickbooks Desktop. The exchange would be like the invoices, payments,transactions etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by downloading the QuickBooks SDK:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb/0020_get_set_up/sdk_downloads

Install it, and look at the file named:

- QuickBooks Web Connector Programmers Guide, `QBWC_proguide.pdf`

It's about 100 pages, and a spec/guide of what you'll need to implement since there's not much else out there pre-built for RoR.

At a (very) high level, you're going to create a SOAP service which listens for HTTP requests. There's a number of methods you'll need to implement:

- `authenticate(...)` - QuickBooks will call this to authenticate to your service
- `sendRequestXML(...)` - QuickBooks will call this to ask "What data do you want to exchange?" at which time you respond with a qbXML request telling to add an invoice, or add a customer, or give you a list of customers, or etc. etc. etc.
- `receiveResponseXML(...)` - When QuickBooks has finished doing whatever it is you told it to do in the previous step, it will call this method to let you know what happened (e.g. was whatever you told it to do successful or not).

There's more details here that you should read:

- http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector

The QuickBooks SDK also includes examples in C# and Java for this. Look for the Web Connector-specific ones, not the COM/QBFC examples (those aren't relevent to you).

You might also look at this for reference/ideas (it's in PHP, but might still serve as a reference):

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php
- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector.php

Comment: Thanks a lot Keith. Will try the above suggestions.

Comment: I am following the steps mentioned above. I have a doubt , the client has the Quickbooks Desktop installed in one of its systems. Is there a way to replicate the same Quickbooks on my system to perform the integration with the new custom web application without needing to buy Quickbooks Desktop again?

Comment: You will need to buy QuickBooks or otherwise obtain a valid license to install it on your computer. You can buy the QuickBooks NFR license which can (sometimes) be cheaper.